# Bootstrap 4 на float

Tags: css, bootstrap4

Подскажите пожалуйста, планирую использовать для верстки bootstrap 4.
На официальном сайте v4.0.0-alpha.6. Но там используется flexbox.
Есть ли версия bootstrap 4 на  float?

Comment: используйте тогда bootstrap 3!

Answer (score 5):

Только Bootstrap 3. По тому как , это было один из главных критерий перехода на Flexbox. Почитай документацию....